# Healthy Crawl Rate

Tags: search

I have a farm with 250,000 items, the average crawl rate is 19 DPS.  Its a 3 server farm, one WFE on APP Server and one sql server.

However I need to know if that is a healthy rate or too slow.

Comment: How long does that take? I usually judge by time based on my volume.

Comment: it takes 4 hours and a half, but in another client we had a DPS of 45-80 in average.

Comment: Someone once told me that everything with 2 digits is usually good enough. We got something around the same DPS although much more documents which results in 24h+ full crawls.

Comment: Was their farm significantly different? Search is very DB intensive. We have about a million at 23 hours, so I'd say that is good not great based on your other experiences.

Comment: there were 6 servers on the other farm, 2 WFE, 2AppServer, another WFE for crawling only and another APP Server for CPC and crawling component.  On this one everything is on the same server.

Comment: Today our servers take 3h+ for full crawl 16000 Items..any idea what is the reason? I have check logs could not find something useful. DPS is 3.8.